# I cannot access the Gii function of the Yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, gii

I have a problem with the gii function in my project.

Error: `The file or directory to be published does not exist: C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2/gii/assets`

The mistake I think is because the path is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are in the **DEV** environement (YII_ENV_DEV). Check the file **web.php** in the config **folder**.

Comment: Thanks I managed to create a new project directly as dev.